# Jquery: Progress bar not working

Tags: jquery

I have written a ajax function to upload a file which works but the progress bar doesn't show the progress of the file upload.  The progress bar will show 100% when the file has uploaded but won't show any progress before its fully uploaded.

```
function ajaxfilefn(path, sdata, progressbar)
{

function progressHandler (e)
{
     $(progressbar).prop({value: e.loaded, max: e.total});
}

return $.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhr: function () { 
        var custom_xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (custom_xhr.upload){custom_xhr.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);}
        return custom_xhr;
    },
    method: "post",
    data: sdata,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false

});
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: what is the method you are using for uploading a file? I believe there are some methods where progress is not triggered

Comment: I'm using the function above to send the post data to a php script which then does move_uploaded_file function.

Comment: Does updating the progressbar's properties change it's state? usually  no.

Comment: Also, note that there are two different phases of progress. The upload, and then the response. The response doesn't show a progress unless it's a very large response. You likely want to know the progress of the upload instead (aka add an event listener to .upload) See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realize I wasn't adding my listener progress function to xhr.upload.  Now that i fixed that, it now works.

Comment: Please indicate that the question is resolved by marking an answer as correct with the check mark or writing your own answer and accept it. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different phases of progress: The upload, and then the response. What you are currently listening to is the response. To listen to the upload add the event to the `xhr.upload` object.

```
...(custom_xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',...
```